# Multiple NgTemplate in angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I have Angular 7 project. And I wrote `<ng-template>` and it's sending my `rowData`. When I wrote one `ng-template` like below, everything working perfectly. But, I need multiple ng-template. I tried something like below. But, I couldn't execute. How can I achieve this?

---

---

---

### This working perfectly

**app.grid.component.html**

```
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData>
  <tr>
    <td *ngFor="let col of Columns" class="ui-resizable-column">
      <span>{{rowData[col.field]}}</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <ng-template *ngTemplateOutlet="templateRef; context : {rowData : rowData}"></ng-template>
    </td>
  </tr>
</ng-template>
```

**app.grid.component.ts**

```
export class GridComponent implements OnInit {
    @ContentChild(TemplateRef) templateRef: TemplateRef<any>;
  }
```

**mycomponent.html**

```
 <app-grid>
   <ng-template let-rowData="rowData">
       <button type="button" label="Update" (click)="update(rowData)"
   </ng-template>
 </app-grid>
```

---

---

---

### But I want multiple like below

**app.grid.component.html**

```
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData>
  <tr>
    <td *ngFor="let col of Columns" class="ui-resizable-column">
      <span>{{rowData[col.field]}}</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <ng-template *ngTemplateOutlet="templateRef; context : {rowData : rowData}"></ng-template>
    </td>
    <td>
      <ng-template *ngTemplateOutlet="templateRef2; context : {rowData : rowData}"></ng-template>
    </td>
  </tr>
</ng-template>
```

**app.grid.component.ts**

```
export class GridComponent implements OnInit {
    @ContentChild(TemplateRef) templateRef: TemplateRef<any>;
    @ContentChild(TemplateRef) templateRef2: TemplateRef<any>;
  }
```

**mycomponent.html**

```
 <app-grid>
   <ng-template let-rowData="rowData" [ngForTemplate]="templateRef">
       <button type="button" label="Delete" (click)="delete(rowData)"></button>
   </ng-template>
   <ng-template let-rowData="rowData" [ngForTemplate]="templateRef2">
       <button type="button" label="Update" (click)="update(rowData)"></button>
   </ng-template>
 </app-grid>
```

Comment: is there any error in your console?

Comment: My console giving **Can't bind to 'ngForTemplate' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-template'** @BearNithi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer. You can see from this stackblitz link. (This stackblitz is not exactly the same. But logic is exatly same.)

[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d7nzqd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `@ContentChildren` instead of `@ContentChild`

```
@ContentChildren(TemplateRef) tabs: QueryList<TemplateRef>;
```

Comment: But, how I can give ID to templateRef, if I use List like your said. In other words , how angular know which ngtemplate write to which ngtemplate. @BearNithi.

Comment: But, how I can give Id to templateRef. in other words , how angular know which ngtemplate write to which ngtemplat @BearNithi.

Comment: You can loop over it.

Comment: I add your code to my `app.grid.component.ts` to my working code. And I changed `app.grid.component.html` as `<ng-template *ngTemplateOutlet="tabs; context : {rowData : rowData}"></ng-template>` . My console giving error **templateRef.createEmbeddedView is not a function** .and  my columns coming as empty.  @BearNithi

Answer (score 0):

Hasan Ozdemir, you can use [@ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) for this,

**Component.ts**

> create templates with `TemplateRef` and then select the template variable in the component to display,

```
 @ViewChild("template1") template1: TemplateRef<any>;
 @ViewChild("template2") template2: TemplateRef<any>;
 selectedTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;
```

**Component.html**

> Do some changes in your template below

```
 <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="selectedTemplate; context : {rowData : rowData}"></ng-container>


<app-grid>
   <ng-template #template1>
       <button type="button" label="Delete" (click)="delete(rowData)"></button>
   </ng-template>
   <ng-template #template2>
       <button type="button" label="Update" (click)="update(rowData)"></button>
   </ng-template>
</app-grid>
```

if you want to display multiple Templates at a time then use [@ViewChildren](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren) instead of `@ViewChild`. I hope this will give you something to understand about `ngTemplates` :)

**UPDATE :**

you need set the template to `selectedTemplate` which you want to display.
But I think you need to display multiple templates so do some changes to your html file. So you may remove `selectedTemplate` in your component.

```
    <td>
      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="template1; context : {rowData : rowData}"></ng-container>
    </td>
    <td>
      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="template2; context : {rowData : rowData}"></ng-container>
    </td>
```

Comment: Thanks @ganesh045 . I change my codes like your said. My console not giving any error. But, my columns coming as empty. I wrote  `myComponent.html` like this. Is it true?   `<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData>
  <tr>
    <td *ngFor="let col of Columns">
      <span>{{rowData[col.field]}}</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <ng-template *ngTemplateOutlet="selectedTemplate; context : {rowData : rowData}"></ng-template>
    </td>
    <td>
      <ng-template *ngTemplateOutlet="selectedTemplate; context : {rowData : rowData}"></ng-template>
    </td>
  </tr>
</ng-template>`

Comment: I tried but it's not worked. Colums are empty again @ganesh045

Comment: use `ng-container` instead of `ng-template` it will work @Hasan Ozdemir, answer was updated with `ng-container` :)

Comment: It didn't worked :) @ganesh045  .Colums are empty again

Comment: is there any reason to put your templates inside `<app-grid>`..? If no remove that once and try it

Comment: Yes. It's required. Because, I'm managing all grids in my application from one component. @ganesh045